# Error message; Cannot access class 'androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, composable

I am making a QR Code Scanner app using Jetpack compose. But when I am trying to use Column, the composable function then the compiler is giving me this error:
***Cannot access class 'androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies***

Here is my app build.gradle module for the app:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.plcoding.qrcodescannercompose"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.5")
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    // Activity Compose
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0"

    // CameraX
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.1.0-beta01"

    // Zxing
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
}
```

Update: This is the code that is generating the error:
[image]

I don't know what this error message is saying and how to resolve this?

Comment: Show the code which produces the error

Comment: Hey, @PhilipDukhov I have updated the information.

Comment: checkout the implementation here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dGLj3lZkrw&t=329s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to upgrade your version of Compose to the latest stable version which is 1.1.0-rc03

If your project consists of multiple modules, make sure that all of them are using the same version of Compose.